# how to call Activity class from Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, slidingmenu, navigation-drawer

I am working with Navigation Drawer and i want to call testActivity.java class when someone click on a item that is in the sliding menu.Currently my MainActivity.java calss is calling to the FragmentOne,FragmentTwo,FragmentThree when sliding menu item selected..I want to replace this with testActivity.java

here is my MainActivity.java

```
 public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
final String[] data ={"one","two","three"};
final String[] fragments ={
        "core.layout.FragmentOne",
        "core.layout.FragmentTwo",
        "core.layout.FragmentThree"};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>    (getActionBar().getThemedContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);

     final DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
     final ListView navList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
     navList.setAdapter(adapter);
     navList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
             @Override
             public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int pos,long id){
                     drawer.setDrawerListener( new DrawerLayout.SimpleDrawerListener(){
                             @Override
                             public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView){
                                     super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                                     FragmentTransaction tx = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                                     tx.replace(R.id.main, Fragment.instantiate(MainActivity.this, fragments[pos]));
                                     tx.commit();
                             }
                     });
                     drawer.closeDrawer(navList);
             }
     });
     FragmentTransaction tx = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
     tx.replace(R.id.main,Fragment.instantiate(MainActivity.this, fragments[0]));
     tx.commit();
}
```

}

here is my FragmentOne.java calss..All other FragmentTwo and FragmentThree.java classes having same code like this.

```
      public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {


public static Fragment newInstance(Context context) {
    FragmentOne f = new FragmentOne();

    return f;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, null);

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one,container, false);

   return root;


}
```

}

This is my testActivity.java class

```
   public class testActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.test);


}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fragment you can access its parent FragmentActivity instance using getActivity(). And since that instance is an activity, so using that you can call another activity simply.

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent((ParentActivity)getActivity(), YourOtherActivity.class);
(ParentActivity)getActivity().startActivity(myIntent);
```

Comment: You mean like this in FragmentOne class?..but its not working?    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), testActivity.class);
        getActivity().startActivity(intent);

Comment: I have put them on like this.No errors or runtime errors.but simply not displaying the layout file..                                      .           public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, null);
      
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one,container, false);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), testActivity.class);
        getActivity().startActivity(intent);
    
       return root;
        

    }

Comment: Try casting your getActivity to ParentActivity. I have edited my answer to add sample code.

Comment: okay.. dont do it in onCreateView(). Do it in onViewCreated(). Probably thats the problem..

Comment: onCreateVicew() is the place where view is still getting created and you may not able to access parent instance. In onViewCreated(), you can access the parent instance.

Comment: Yes Activity class is working nicely.but app does not showing the Navigation Drawer(Sliding menu) and it showing testActivity .when i comment these lines /*Intent myIntent = new Intent((MainActivity)getActivity(), testActivity.class);
       getActivity().startActivity(myIntent); */
         then sliding menu is displaying.i think i have put that code in wrong place.Currently they are on "onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState)" of FragmentOne.java. pls tell me where to put them

Comment: . i want to display NavigationDrawer first and then according to the user click event showing appropriate layout file by calling its Activity class..i have put them on onViewCreated().but still displaying testAcvitity layout first.(its showing MainActivity and call testActivity immediately so no chance to click the sliding menu )

Comment: yes onViewCreated() will automatically be called after fragmnet is created. You need to write a listener for the button of view on click of which you want to lauch new activity. In that listener, onClick(), write this code